# Moving the data from the current in-house CRM to Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, migration, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Context:

The project is to move functionalities from the current in-house CRM build in .NET with its data stored in SQL Server, to a new CRM running on Microsoft Dynamics 365 Online.

The plan is to move one module at the time. For example, the current CRM has five modules, and we had moved the module 1 to the new CRM. The user must go to the new CRM for using module 1, and then go back to the current CRM for using modules 2 to 5. This will go on until all the modules are in the new CRM.

To migrate and/or synchronize the data, we use the KingswaySoft SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

Challenge:

In this context and based on the following, what is the optimal option to move the data from the current in-house CRM to Microsoft Dynamics 365?

Synchronization:

Once we start to move the modules, any new data must be synchronized between the CRM until the old one is completely decommissioned.

Option 1 for data synchronization between the old and the new CRM
When a module moved to the new CRM, synchronize its data between the two CRMs. The user must enter data in the new CRM, and it is synchronized back to the current one, so the other modules not moved yet can use the data entered in the new CRM.

Option 2 for data synchronization between the old and the new CRM
Rather than having synchronization, the user must do the double entry. This can be unpopular, but you avoid data synchronization routines which can cause delays, development, testing and maintenance.

Migration:

All previous data entered in the old CRM also need to be accessible in the new CRM.

Option 1 for data migration from the old CRM to the new CRM
Once all the modules are moved to the new CRM, a migration of all the data is done before the current CRM is decommissioned. There is a sequence in which the data is moved because of dependencies inherent in the current data model.

Option 2 for data migration from the old CRM to the new CRM
Executing a bulk data migration related the module once it is moved to the new CRM. This implies that no update must be done on the related data. The sequence of moving the modules does not necessarily match the sequence of its underlined data that must match the data model.

Option 3 for data migration from the old CRM to the new CRM
Do not migrate the old data to the new CRM all, but connecting them via connectors (API). In this case old data must only be used as read only purposes for dashboards, reports, views and insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow, Patrick.

All the options you mentioned are valid strategies to migrate to an online environment. Choosing one over another will really depend on your project requirements and deadlines. The most straightforward approach would be Migration Option 1, and we have a [Migration Starter Pack](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/blog/2016/09/16/Announcing-Migration-Starter-Pack-for-CRM-Online-and-CRM-On-Premise) you can use as a reference.

Don't hesitate to reach out to us if you require any further assistance.